# I Can't See Any Single Word in ListView

Tags: vb.net, listview

Xperts.

Using VB.net, I tried to put filenames of .txt in a folder into a listview.
No error was found but I couldn't see any single word in the listview.
I wonder if it's caused by obj setting.
The source is as below:

```
Private Sub FolderBrowsing(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnBrowse2.Click

    Dim folderPath As String = tbPath2.Text

    If FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        tbPath2.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
    End If

    folderPath = tbPath2.Text

    Dim fileNames = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(folderPath, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.txt")

    For Each i As String In fileNames

        FileNameList.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(i))

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Check fileNames contains any file or not when you search for files.

Comment: What is the display type? Is it set to Details?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you instanciatiing a new ListViewItem, when you can simply display the file name;

```
For Each i As String In fileNames

    FileNameList.Items.Add(i)

Next
```

However, it will be displaying the full path of the file. In case you only need the file name, you will need to split the string.

Answer (score 0):

Add this Librery :

```
Imports System.IO
```

Replace code :

```
For Each i As String In fileNames

    FileNameList.Items.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(i))

Next
```